# If you don't hit a button in iOS Safari RIGHT ON the click event wont' fire

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, user-experience

I had users of my PWA app complaining that they sometimes had to click a button maybe 2-10 times for it to fire. I *could* not figure out what caused this. First I thought that maybe it was due to an error in my code or a bad internet connection, but then I realized it:

**If you don't hit a button in iOS Safari RIGHT ON the click event wont' fire.**

**In other words:** If you tap the button with your finger, and then move your finger slightly in either direction, even just a few millimeters, and then release your finger, the click event wont' fire.

This seems to be happening quite a lot for regular human users, and they are left frustrated over what's happening (or not happening), without knowing why, or blaming my code.

I think the click event should fire if you release your finger while still being inside the button-area. This is the default behavior in Chrome for Windows at least.

Is there a solution to this? Trust me, I've been Googling this a lot and tried many different things, from different event-handlers to JS tap-libraries.

**EDIT:** The same thing seems to happen if you hold your finger down for more than just a split-second.

Here's a link to a PWA test app that I made containing a simple button and the code below: [the link has been removed]

Feel free to "download" the PWA by opening it in Safari and then hit Share -> Add to Home Screen.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!document.body.contains(e.target)) {
        return;
    }

    if (e.target.matches('#testButton')) {
        alert('Button clicked!');
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="testButton">Click me to test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by [a bug in Safari Mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#Safari_Mobile). I solved the problem by adding `onclick="void(0)"` to all of my buttons, like this:

```html
<div id="testButton" class="button" onclick="void(0)">Click me to test</div>
```